# Rewriting coefficients of a regression

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, stata, coefficient-of-variation

We are interested in the variable $\alpha_1$, in the equation

$
y_{iv1}=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1group_v+x_ia_x+ \gamma y_{iv0} + \epsilon_{iv1} 
$

Where $y_{iv1}$ is a dummy variable, and $x_ia_x$ denotes a matrix of other independent variables.
Now suppose there is a new dummy variable $\textit{followup}$.
Is it possible to still capture the effect of $\alpha_1$ within the next equation?

$
y_{iνt} = β_0 + β_1group_ν + β_2followup_t + β_3followup_t · group_ν + x_iβ_x + ε_{iνt}, t = 0, 1
$

I thought that it might be $(\beta_1+\beta_3followup_t)$.

Also, since everything is done in stata. How should I calculate the standard error of this term?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the model used, if you are using factor notation, that is straightforward.
say:

```
reg y x
margins, dydx(x)
reg y x z c.x#c.z
margins, dydx(x)
```

they both will produce the marginal effect of x on y, as the one you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the equation that you wrote down. Of course, for the followup regressor you need the exogeneity given for consistent estimation. with respect to the calculation in stata @Fcold provided the approach I would take as well.

Comment: One further thing that i want to add. The exogeneity assumption is now a little bit more stronger if you have interaction terms in your regression. You now need uncorrelation of the error term with any function of the regressor "group"